# RichTextBox Undo process for custom UIContainer

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have RichTextBox in WPF  which contains `InlineUIContainer` with some custom objects. How to allow Undo event for that UIContainer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all bind a command to your undo button.
Write a [CommandBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) similar to this:
`<CommandBinding Command="Undo" Executed="ExecuteUndo" CanExecute="CanExecuteUndo"/>`

Then set the `Content` of the RichTextBox to something like this

`{Binding myUndoManager.CurrentContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}`

`myUndoManager` is a DependencyProperty with type of `UndoManager` class. You need to implement this class and inherit it from `DependencyObject` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. within this class, `CurrentContent` is a `DependencyProperty` which keeps the proper content to show and `PropertyChanged` event handles every changes to the `Content` of the RichTextBox. *(you can add a collection to the class and with each call to this event, add a new item to the collection. the type of the items for this collection might have some properties like TextDifferences, ActionType, ...)*

Then all that is left is to implement the body of `CanExecuteUndo` and `ExecuteUndo` inside your code. *(`e.CanExecute` could be set to true inside the `CanExecuteUndo`, if and only if the collection is not empty. And `ExecuteUndo` pops out the last item from the collection and according to its `ActionType` does the necessary actions)*

And don't forget to set the `DataContext` of the window(or RichTextBox) to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` if `myUndoManager` object is in the same class as the window.